# how i can use Distinct in Query with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, distinct

I have a query from my products and factors and factor items for show them.

In this query I'm showing a report from factor for user.

My query is :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FactoriTems.datesave ASC) AS rn,
        FactoriTems.code, FactoriTems.replacement, 
        FactoriTems.suggcode, Factors.dateexport,
        Productions.descriptions, 
        FactoriTems.countt, FactoriTems.price, 
        FactoriTems.countt * FactoriTems.price AS 'total', 
        Productions.country             
    FROM 
        Productions 
    INNER JOIN 
        FactoriTems ON Productions.code = FactoriTems.code
    INNER JOIN 
        Factors ON Factors.gid = FactoriTems.gid
    WHERE 
        (FactoriTems.gid = @gid)
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY rn
```

This query is OK, but there is a problem, in `Productions` table some category have two or three product with one code, and when this codes are in `factoritems` table show two rows in my result set!

Result is :

| rn | code | dateexport | descriptions | countt | price | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 12/24/2021 | ... | 100 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | bbb | 12/24/2021 | ... | 200 | 3 | 600 |
| 3 | ccc | 12/24/2021 | ... | 100 | 2 | 200 |
| 4 | ddd | 12/24/2021 | ... | 200 | 3 | 600 |
| 5 | ddd | 12/24/2021 | ... | 100 | 2 | 200 |
| 6 | eee | 12/24/2021 | ... | 200 | 3 | 600 |

Now how can I show only one row for `'ddd'` product code?

I tried to use `DISTINCT` but I got an error.

I want the output to be as follows:

| rn | code | dateexport | descriptions | countt | price | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 12/24/2021 | ... | 100 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | bbb | 12/24/2021 | ... | 200 | 3 | 600 |
| 3 | ccc | 12/24/2021 | ... | 100 | 2 | 200 |
| 4 | ddd | 12/24/2021 | ... | 200 | 3 | 600 |
| 5 | eee | 12/24/2021 | ... | 200 | 3 | 600 |

Thanks

Comment: use partition by product code in row number  and then retrieve a single value for every product and then apply row_number() on final query.

Comment: @RahulBiswas I'm really grateful for the help, but my sort is very important to me based on the "FactoriTems.datesave", and when I use the partition, that sort breaks down. Another problem is that when I use the partition, my row number crashes, but the row number is also important to me.

Comment: I would suggest you think through your joins carefully, as just chucking `DISTINCT` or `ROW_NUMBER()` at a query probably isn't helpful. Why are you getting duplicates in the first place? Which join is causing that, and how can you get that join to return a single row? These are the questions you need to ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just missing `PARTITIN BY` clause for the `code` column within the inner query. Rewrite your current query such as

```sql
WITH CTE AS
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ft.code ORDER BY ft.datesave) AS rn0,         
         ft.code,
         ft.replacement,
         ft.suggcode,
         f.dateexport,
         p.descriptions,
         ft.countt,
         ft.price,
         ft.countt * ft.price AS total,
         p.country
    FROM Productions p
    JOIN FactoriTems ft
      ON p.code = ft.code
    JOIN Factors f
      ON f.gid = ft.gid
   WHERE (ft.gid = @gid))
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datesave,code) AS rn, 
       code, replacement, suggcode, dateexport, descriptions,
       countt, price, total, country   
  FROM CTE 
 WHERE rn0 = 1
 ORDER BY rn
```

in order to filter out the duplicates for each distinct grouped `code`

Comment: thanks for your help, but my sort is very important to me based on the "FactoriTems.datesave", and when I use the partition, that sort breaks down. Another problem is that when I use the partition, my row number crashes, but the row number is also important to me.

Comment: OK @hamo , consider using this new query then

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT ROW_Number() over (PARTITION BY FactoriTems.code ORDER by FactoriTems.datesave ASC) as rn,FactoriTems.code, 
        FactoriTems.replacement, FactoriTems.suggcode,Factors.dateexport,
        Productions.descriptions, FactoriTems.countt, FactoriTems.price, 
        FactoriTems.countt * FactoriTems.price AS 'total', Productions.country              
FROM Productions 
    INNER JOIN FactoriTems ON Productions.code = FactoriTems.code
    INNER JOIN Factors ON Factors.gid = FactoriTems.gid
WHERE (FactoriTems.gid = @gid)) 
SELECT  *   FROM CTE 
WHERE CTE.rn  = 1
ORDER BY rn
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but i get error in WHERE ROW_Number() : "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses."

Comment: Try again @hamo

Comment: The order of the show is messed up like this :(

Comment: you can work on ORDER by FactoriTems.datesave ASC or Desc  !!!